# textEntry.Text output is Gtk.Entry (mono)

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin-studio, gtk#, gtkentry

I try to get the text of an Entry with this code:

```
this.myEntry.Text();
```

also I have tried:

```
this.myEntry.Text.ToString();
this.myEntry.ToString();
```

But all what I get is **Gtk.Entry** and not the text from the Entry. How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use

```
string text = this.myEntry.Text;
```